# How can I recursively convert a nested array to a flat array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, nested

I'm trying to get this nested array to a flat array. While using this way to solve it seems every time I callback arrayFlattener(element) the newArr become a empty array. Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

```js
const arrayFlattener = (arr) => {
    let newArr = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let element = arr[i];
        if (Array.isArray(element)){
            newArr.push(arrayFlattener(element));
            
        } else {
            newArr.push(element);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
console.log(arrayFlattener(['I', 'am', 'working', ['on', 'another', 'level']]));
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you tagged this question with the language you're working in. (I'd do it for you, but I don't recognize the syntax.)

Comment: Is performance the requirement for using recursion?

Comment: Are you looking for general recursion, tail recursion, or iterative recursion?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
let newArr = ['I', 'am', 'working', ['on', 'another', 'level']].flatMap(el=>el);

console.log(newArr);
```

or use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flat(); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4]

var arr2 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr2.flat();
// [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]

var arr3 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr3.flat(2); // depth argument to flatten the array
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I agree, if you need to implement recursion you can do how @Andreas answered
but also I believe browser implementation will be faster than implementing a recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Your code and theory are fine. You just chose the wrong method. Use `concat` instead of `push` (to extend the result rather than insert into it):

```js
const arrayFlattener = (arr) => {
    let newArr = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let element = arr[i];
        if (Array.isArray(element)){
            newArr = newArr.concat(arrayFlattener(element));
            
        } else {
            newArr.push(element);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
console.log(arrayFlattener(['I', 'am', 'working', ['on', 'another', 'level']]));
```

Answer (score 2):

`flat` do the job with the `depth` `param` level specifying how deep a nested array structure should be flattened.

**Example**

```js
const arr = ['I', 'am', 'working', ['on', 'another', 'level'], 'now', ["now", ["hello", "you you"]]]

console.log(arr.flat(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your function did not flatten the array, but simply parse through every individual element of the array. It still returns the same array structure.

To flatten the array, you should pass the resulting array as well, so that the individual element can be pushed straight into the resulting array instead of making another array and push it to the resulting array (which produce the same initial array structure)

```js
let newArr = [];
const arrayFlattener = (arr, result) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let element = arr[i];
        if (Array.isArray(element)){
            result = arrayFlattener(element, result);
            
        } else {
            result.push(element);
        }
    }
    return result
}
console.log(arrayFlattener(['I', 'am', 'working', ['on', 'another', 'level'], 'now'], newArr));
```

Comment: Why not use flattenMap?

Comment: This seems a little weird. I think it's more common to enter just an input and expect a result rather than entering both an input and a pointer to the result, unless the latter is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

## Here's three solutions

You can use `.flatMap` and recursion or

```js
const flatten = (xs) =>
  Array.isArray(xs) ? xs.flatMap(flatten) : [xs]

const array = ['I', 'am', 'working', ['on', 'another', ['level']]]

console.log(flatten(array))
```

you can use `.reduce` and recursion

```js
const flatten = (xs) =>
  xs.reduce(
    (y, x) => y.concat(Array.isArray(x) ? flatten(x) : [x]),
    [])

const array = ['I', 'am', 'working', ['on', 'another', ['level']]]

console.log(flatten(array))
```

or even better just use `.flat`

```js
const flatten = (xs) =>
  xs.flat(Infinity)

const array = ['I', 'am', 'working', ['on', 'another', ['level']]]

console.log(flatten(array))
```